# Is there an event handler for a Selection being made using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, python-addin

I want to be able to capture an arcpy.SelectByAttribute() or arcpy.SelectByLocation() event being triggered. There doesn't seem to be an extension that is able to handle this.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are others who will be able to provide you a more developer oriented answer than this but when I read the **[Creating a Python add-in application extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000018000000)** page it says:

> Application extensions are usually responsible for listening and
>   responding to various events exposed by the host application.

The same page shows some of the events that are listened to in a graphic but surprisingly does not seem to describe them in detail.

The host application is ArcMap, and so I would think that events listened to would be at most those from the arcpy.mapping module which allows you access to some of the ArcObjects that "drive" ArcMap.  However, arcpy.SelectByLocation and arcpy.SelectByAttribute are not from arcpy.mapping so I think the answer is likely to be that you will not be able to use a Python Addin to do this.

Consequently, to do this you may need to use [ArcObjects to Customize ArcGIS for Desktop by writing add-ins or building custom components in .NET or Java](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Developing_with_ArcGIS/01w200000002000000/)