# Automatically Panning to Point Created with Absolute X,Y?

Tags: arcmap, pan

I'm currently working on a project where I have a many sets of XY coordinates along with corresponding marked aerial imagery (all on paper) from which I'm creating a feature class for a database.

After I enter each set of coordinates, I would like for ArcMap to automatically pan to the newly-created point, which would make it easier for me to reference it against the aerial imagery. (I'm currently right-clicking the feature on the Attribute Table and selecting "Pan.")

I feel like this should be easy/obvious, but I'm having no luck.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Following @Kate's instructions on [Zoom to Selected Feature Keyboard Shortcut](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/235174/zoom-to-selected-feature-keyboard-shortcut), I created a keyboard shortcut for Pan to Selected Features (e.g. Ctrl-Shift-1). When creating a point using Absolute XY value (F6), I see that the feature is automatically selected. I was then able to use my created keyboard shortcut to quickly pan there.

1. customize
2. customize mode
3. keyboard
4. layer category
5. pan to selected feature command
6. assign it a new shortcut key

There may be some Event that gets triggered on point creation (OnEdit?) which you could use instead.

Comment: The event is OnCreateFeature https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0020000000p6000000 but that requires the user to know some VB.net or C# and have the SDK installed; according to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73474/is-there-an-event-handler-for-a-selection-being-made-using-arcpy there is some confusion about responding to events in python.. I like the shortcut method you've shown, I use Alt+Key for shortcuts and stick to the left side of the keyboard (I'm right handed) so mouse in one hand, the other works on shortcuts.. Alt+Z would work.